# Linux - Find a string and get the next section

Tags: linux, sed, awk

If I have a string like "name":"tempname","department":"tempdept", I want to search for the value for "department" which is "tempdept". So if "department" exists, I need just the value returned. The length of the string that is searched can be very long. Is this possible using sed/awk, can you please help?

I tried the following, but it returns the whole string. I am searching for department here.

```
echo $data | sed 's/\(\"department\":\)\(.*\"\)/\2/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this does it for you:

```
sed -ne '/"department"/{s/^.*"department":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/;p;}'
```

Example:

```
echo '"name":"tempname","department":"tempdept"' | sed -ne '/"department"/{s/^.*"department":"\([^"]*\).*/\1/;p;}'
tempdept
```

If you need to retain the double quotes, just add them back in during the replacement:

```
    sed -ne '/"department"/{s/^.*"department":"\([^"]*\).*/"\1"/;p;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some simple solutions:

```
echo "$data" | tr , \\n | awk -F: '$1 ~ /^department$/{ print $2 }'
```

or

```
echo "$data" | awk -F: '$1 ~ /^department$/{ print $2 }' RS=,
```

Your solution just need minor modifications:

```
echo "$data" | tr , \\n | sed -n 's/"department":\(.*\)/\2/p'
```

or

```
echo "$data" | tr , \\n | sed -n '/"department":/s///p'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The modified sed solution below does work, but the result gets truncated when it hits a comma in the department value. So assuming the the value of the department always ends with a double quote, can we retrieve till that character including the quote?                                     echo "$data" | tr , \\n | sed -n '/"department":/s///p'